# Designing in proprotion for Flex Printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, dpi

I want to design a flex banner of (90 Feet X 4 Feet) @ 72dpi.
But i cant open a work book of such size in Illustrator.
Can you please guide me on how to design the banner using the idea of a sizing the design in proportionality.

Thank you

Comment: Hi user51365, see relevant questions - [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be) and [Best workflow for editing massive posters/banners for print in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/best-workflow-for-editing-massive-posters-banners-for-print-in-photoshop) and [Planning an 18 foot long banner](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37902/planning-an-18-foot-long-banner)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here.

1) A real one. You need a 90 foot banner.

2) One that you asume. 72 ppi.*

The good news is that you are working in ilustrator.

You have 2 options to play with.

**a)** Scale your project down. Try making it at 1/10 try using 150-200ppi

**b)** Work in panels

You are asumming you need 72 ppi, which could be not the case. Take a look to this graph. [Large Format Photograph Printing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60323/large-format-photograph-printing/60534#60534)

Your project is a tricky one becouse you have a height of 4 foot, which leads me to thing that it is a sidewalk or something. That is why you can think of individual pannels. Lets say each pannel measures 8x4 foot. Then use that graph to think about the **real resolution of the raster elements** of each pannel.

If you choose to scale it down, the final raster elements will be scaled up again.

You don't need to worry about texts. Leave them on vectors.

Comment: Regarding point a): assuming the OP has the 72dpi spec correct, Illustrator CS4 max artboard is about 220-something inches, which is about 19 feet. 19 feet is about 1/4 of 90 feet. So if the OP makes the artboard 19 feet wide @ 300 dpi, the effective resolution at 90 feet is about 72dpi. (increase the DPI (4x) by the same factor that the size has been decreased (1/4))